# Regex pattern for Validating phone number

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have a input string ("My phone number is 860-678 - 2345"). From the input string I need to validate phone number using Regex.

I am using the below pattern but it doesn't work if the phone number contains white Space in it.

```
[(]?[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[)-. ,]?[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[-. ,]?[0-9]{4}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `regexkitlite` tag relevant (as you are using C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression:

```
(\([2-9]\d\d\)|[2-9]\d\d) ?[-.,]? ?[2-9]\d\d ?[-.,]? ?\d{4}
```

matches all of the following:

```
860-678-2345
(860) 678-2345
(860) 678 - 2345
```

and probably a fair amount else too. Broken down:

- `(\([2-9]\d\d\)|[2-9]\d\d)` - Matches the first part of the number with or without brackets
- `?[-.,]? ?` - A hyphen, period (or full stop to us Brits) or a comma, with or without surrounding spaces.
- `[2-9]\d\d` - Matches the second part of the number.
- `\d{4}` - Matches the final part of the number.

`\d\d` and `[0-9]{2}` are equivalent; the former is just slightly shorter so improves readability. Likewise, `[2-9]` and `[2-9]{1}` are equivalent; the `{1}` just means "one instance of the preceeding pattern", which is a given anyway.

Comment: I have 2 regex pattern, as mentioned below.
The 1st one works and the 2nd throws an error -- I want to understand what is the difference.

Comment: (\(\d\d\d\)|\d\d\d) ?[-.,]? ?\d\d\d ?[-.,]? ?\d{4}

Comment: (\(\d{3})|\d{3}) ?[-.,]? ?\d{3} ?[-.,]? ?\d{4}

Comment: @JyotiSahu I'm not seeing an error on either. By the way, don't forget that `(` and `)` are special characters in regular expressions, and so need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for spaces seperately before and after the seperating charactors.

```
[(]?[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[)-.,]?[ ]?[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[-.,]?[ ]?[0-9]{4}
```

Keep in mind, this wont actually match the parens so something like `(234-567, 1234` would match. So if you want more strict matching, you will need a much more complicated regex or code the validation using something else.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to first take off all white spaces, and then, you can easily verify your numbers with that RE that you've done.

Comment: The use case here involves finding the phone number within a string, and replacing it with dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

(?\d{3})?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}

[Refer: Regular Expression Liberary](http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)